# Graphics Floating Around

Tags: graphics, floats

I have wrote this piece of LaTeX code

```
\chapter{Datenmodellierung}
\paragraph{Fremdschlüssel}
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{Resources/Included Graphics/foreign_keys_example.png}

\paragraph{Integritätsprüfung via Checks}
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{Resources/Included Graphics/integrity_checking.png}
```

and expected it to look be a heading, then a picture in the next line, then a heading again (in a new line), and finally the second graphic in yet another line.

Unfortunately, it looks like this:
[image]

So maybe using figures hel ... no, it doesn't:

```
\chapter{Datenmodellierung}
\paragraph{Fremdschlüssel}
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{Resources/Included Graphics/foreign_keys_example.png}
\end{figure}

\paragraph{Integritätsprüfung via Checks}
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{Resources/Included Graphics/integrity_checking.png}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

I of course googled the problem and found a solution: Inserting float barriers and using the package `placeins`.

I inserted them like this

```
\chapter{Datenmodellierung}
\paragraph{Fremdschlüssel}
\FloatBarrier
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{Resources/Included Graphics/foreign_keys_example.png}
\end{figure}

\FloatBarrier
\paragraph{Integritätsprüfung via Checks}
\FloatBarrier
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{Resources/Included Graphics/integrity_checking.png}
\end{figure}
```

and somehow it got even worse:

[image]

I'd like to stop stuff from floating around altogether. Is this possible?

I already use the package `float` and `H`s behind table declarations (`\begin{table}[H]`) to stop them from floating all over the place. However, that doesn't help with the graphics floating around.

The article type is `report`.

Comment: Don't use the `figure` environment, if you want to place a graphic object just there with no caption. There's no rule that mandates `\includegraphics` to be in a `figure` environment.

Comment: If I don't use figures, the float barriers don't have any effect at all.

Comment: And what would be the purpose of `\FloatBarrier` if there's nothing to float around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard behavior of `\paragraph` is to print the heading in-line.

If you want a line break after the heading, type

```
\paragraph{Fremdschlüssel}\mbox{}\\*
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{Resources/Included Graphics/foreign_keys_example.png}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But do you know how to stop figures from floating before and after lines generally?

Comment: @UTF-8 If you don't want them to float, just don't use the `figure` environment (and don't give them captions).

Comment: Ah, when writing a `report`, I can center graphics without putting them into figures. I didn't know this is possible. It doesn't seem to be possible when using document type `beamer`, though.